# Pandas - delete rows with all zeros and delete columns using index of deleted rows

Tags: pandas

My `df` is a square sparse matrix, with the shape:
`(3862, 3862)`

```
      0   1    ... 3862
0     0.0 0.0      0.0
1     0.0 0.0      0.0
...
3862  0.0 0.0  ... 0.0
```

And I need to get rid of rows with only 0.0, like so:

```
df.loc[~(df==0.0).all(axis=1)]
```

After which I end up with s matrix with shape `(3819, 3862)`

---

But I need to keep my matrix square.

So how do I keep track of index of deleted rows, and delete columns from those indexes as well, in order to end up with shape `(3819,3819)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
idx = df.index[(df==0.0).all(axis=1)]
out = df.drop(idx,axis=1).drop(idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
# Simple df example
df = pd.DataFrame(
        [[0, 1, 2],
         [0, 0, 0],
         [3, 0, 0]])

# Condition for rows to be kept
condition = ~(df==0.0).all(axis=1)

# Get the index of rows that satisfy condition
idx2keep = df.loc[condition].index

# Retain the columns and rows with good index
df.loc[idx2keep, idx2keep]
```

OUTPUT:

```
    0   2
0   0   2
2   3   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the transpose operator, `.T`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = [0,1,2,3], data = [
        [0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,1,0],
        ])

empty_rows = (df==0.0).all(axis=1)
df.drop(df.index[empty_rows]).T.drop(df.index[empty_rows]).T
```

output (both row 0 and column 0 got dropped

```
    1   2   3
1   1   0   0
2   0   0   1
3   0   1   0
```

**Alternatively** you can use iloc if you row and column index values line up with their order:

```
df.iloc[df.index[~empty_rows],df.index[~empty_rows]]
```

this produces the same output